# ASP.NET Core MVC & Entity Framework not showing any of the tables in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to see my tables in Visual Studio in an ASP.NET Core MVC application that I have. I'm actually following a tutorial from Mosh Hamedani about it and when I click on the `.mdf` file to open up Server Explorer and the Data Connections row nothing shows up under the DefaultConnection row.

This is strange because I'm able to add records to the database directly as the database objects show up from one session to the next after doing any CRUD operation on them. It looks like in the screenshot below.

[image]

From what I've browsed online, connection strings are normally the reason why a lot of these errors happen but I'm so new to ASP.NET Core MVC, and I have no way of knowing how to troubleshoot the connection string to solve this kind of issue. But I'm going to post it anyway here so that maybe someone willing to help will know what to do it with it.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Vidly-20220707050258.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Vidly-20220707050258;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a connection directly in Server Explorer? Right click Data Connections > Add Connection... > Microsoft SQL Server Database File > Continue > Browse for the .mdf file > Test Connection

Comment: This did it! Mind if I ask what this was doing that wasn't already done as a followup question?

Comment: I would think the Server Explorer pane is an IDE functionality rather than a Solution integrated feature. i.e. the connection string found on the web.config or appsettings.json isn't automatically loaded on the Server Explorer pane.